# What kind of 3-manifolds arise has hypersurfaces in R^4?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

What kind of 3-manifolds can arise as hypersurfaces $\{ f(x,y,z,w) = 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^4$?  Can they have nontrivial H<sup>1</sup> or H<sup>2</sup>?

Comment: What kind of function is $f$? For smooth $f$ you can get
any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a zero set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple construction that bears on the narrow version of John's question:  If $M$ is a closed $n$-manifold that embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (which can only happen if $M$ is orientable), then $M \times S^k$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1+k}$.  Thicken $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, then cross with $I^k$ in the new dimensions, and then take the boundary of that.  By induction, then, any product of spheres embeds in the next dimension.

On the other hand, Ryan Budney in [arXiv:0810.2346](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2346) has both new results and a bibliography of the broad question of which closed 3-manifolds embed in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  It is problem 3.20 in Kirby's problem list, it is an interesting open problem, and there have been several partial results.

Answer (score 0):

$S^1\times\mathbb R^2$ is an hypersurface in $\mathbb R^4$, and so is $S^2\times\mathbb R^1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut a [two-torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) out of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and I think that a simple modification will cut a three-torus out of $\mathbb{R}^4$.  So the answer to your second question is "yes".